# How can I extend the typography in Material UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js

I am creating a custom theme using `createMuiTheme` and my app guideline has more variants of Typography than Material UI. By variants, I mean 'h1', 'h2', 'subtitle1'. My app has more than this. How can I extend the typography so that it matches to what I want?

Here is some code:

```
const rawTheme: Theme = createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    MuiButton: {
      disableElevation: true,
    },
    MuiAppBar: {
      elevation: 0,
    },
    MuiRadio: {
      color: "primary",
    },
    MuiAccordion: {
      elevation: 0,
    },
  },
  overrides: {
    MuiTableCell: {
      sizeSmall: {
        padding: `${pxToRem(6)} ${pxToRem(16)}`,
      },
      footer: {
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        zIndex: 2,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        position: "sticky",
      },
    },
    MuiTableHead: {
      root: {
        "& .MuiTableCell-root": {
          backgroundColor: BaseThemeConfig.colors.primary.main,
          paddingTop: pxToRem(16),
          paddingBottom: pxToRem(16),

          "&:first-child": {
            borderTopLeftRadius: pxToRem(8),
          },
          "&:last-child": {
            borderTopRightRadius: pxToRem(8),
          },

          "& > *": {
            color: "#FFF",
          },
        },
      },
    },
    MuiTableBody: {
      root: {
        "& .MuiTableCell-root": {
          cursor: "pointer",
          borderBottom: `1px solid ${BaseThemeConfig.colors.divider}`,
        },
      },
    },
    MuiTablePagination: {
      toolbar: {
        minHeight: "38px",
      },
      selectRoot: {
        display: "none",
        pointerEvents: "none",
      },
    },
    MuiTouchRipple: {
      child: {
        backgroundColor: BaseThemeConfig.colors.primary.dark,
      },
    },
    MuiDivider: {
      vertical: {
        backgroundColor: BaseThemeConfig.colors.primary.main,
      },
    },
    MuiDrawer: {
      paperAnchorBottom: {
        borderRadius: `${pxToRem(16)} ${pxToRem(16)} 0 0`,
      },
    },
    MuiButton: {
      root: {
        ...BaseThemeConfig.button,
      },
      contained: {
        backgroundColor: BaseThemeConfig.colors.primary.main,
        color: BaseThemeConfig.colors.primary.contrastText,
        "&:hover": {
          backgroundColor: BaseThemeConfig.colors.primary.dark,
        },
        "&$disabled": {
          backgroundColor: BaseThemeConfig.appColors.neutral["400"],
          color: BaseThemeConfig.colors.text.disabled,
        },
        "@media (hover: none)": {
          "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: `${BaseThemeConfig.colors.primary.dark} !important`,
          },
        },
      },
      containedSecondary: {
        backgroundColor: BaseThemeConfig.colors.secondary.main,
        "&:hover": {
          backgroundColor: BaseThemeConfig.colors.primary.light,
          color: BaseThemeConfig.colors.primary.contrastText,
        },
      },
      outlined: {
        borderColor: BaseThemeConfig.colors.primary.main,
        "&:hover": {
          backgroundColor: BaseThemeConfig.colors.primary["100"],
        },
        ...BaseThemeConfig.button,
      },
      textPrimary: {
        color: BaseThemeConfig.colors.text.primary,
      },
      textSecondary: {
        color: BaseThemeConfig.appColors.neutral.main,
      },
      startIcon: {
        marginRight: 18,
      },
    },
    MuiFormHelperText: {
      root: {
        color: BaseThemeConfig.colors.text.secondary,
        fontWeight: 400,
        fontSize: pxToRem(14),
        lineHeight: pxToRem(20),
        letterSpacing: "-0.006em",
        marginTop: pxToRem(8),
      },
    },
    MuiBottomNavigation: {
      root: {
        zIndex: 1,
        boxShadow: "0px -4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
      },
    },
    MuiBottomNavigationAction: {
      root: {
        "& + &": {
          borderLeft: `1px solid ${BaseThemeConfig.colors.divider}`,
        },
      },
      wrapper: {
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        "& > svg": {
          marginRight: pxToRem(16),
        },
        "& > span": {
          fontSize: "14px",
        },
      },
    },
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
      input: {
        fontSize: pxToRem(14),
        lineHeight: pxToRem(20),
        padding: `${pxToRem(14)} ${pxToRem(16)}`,
        color: BaseThemeConfig.colors.text.primary,
        borderColor: BaseThemeConfig.colors.text.disabled,
        "&::placeholder": {
          color: BaseThemeConfig.appColors.neutral.main,
        },
        "&:disabled": {
          background: BaseThemeConfig.appColors.neutral["400"],
          color: BaseThemeConfig.appColors.neutral.main,
        },
      },
      inputMultiline: {
        padding: `${pxToRem(14)} ${pxToRem(16)}`,
      },
      multiline: {
        padding: 0,
      },
    },
    MuiInputLabel: {
      root: {
        marginBottom: pxToRem(8),
      },
    },
    MuiContainer: {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: BaseThemeConfig.colors.primary.contrastText,
      },
    },
    MuiAppBar: {
      root: {
        borderBottom: `1px solid ${BaseThemeConfig.appColors.neutral[400]}`,
      },
    },
    MuiFab: {
      root: {
        position: "fixed",
        bottom: pxToRem(16),
        right: pxToRem(16),
      },
    },
    MuiChip: {
      root: {
        padding: `${pxToRem(6)} ${pxToRem(16)}`,
        boxShadow: "0px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
      },
      label: {
        paddingRight: 0,
        paddingLeft: 0,
      },
      icon: {
        marginRight: pxToRem(4),
      },
    },
    MuiLink: {
      root: {
        textTransform: "none",
      },
    },
    MuiDialogTitle: {
      root: {
        padding: `${pxToRem(24)} ${pxToRem(24)} 0`,
      },
    },
    MuiDialogContent: {
      root: {
        padding: `${pxToRem(24)} ${pxToRem(24)}`,
      },
    },
    MuiDialogActions: {
      root: {
        padding: `0 ${pxToRem(24)} ${pxToRem(24)}`,
      },
    },
    MuiAccordion: {
      root: {
        "&$expanded": {
          margin: 0,
        },
      },
    },
    MuiAccordionSummary: {
      root: {
        padding: `${pxToRem(16)} ${pxToRem(24)}`,
        "&$expanded": {
          minHeight: 0,
        },
      },
      content: {
        margin: 0,
        "&$expanded": {
          margin: 0,
        },
      },
      expandIcon: {
        padding: 0,
        margin: 0,
      },
    },
    MuiAccordionDetails: {
      root: {
        padding: `0 ${pxToRem(12)}`,
        borderTop: `1px solid ${BaseThemeConfig.appColors.neutral["400"]}`,
      },
    },
  },
  typography: {
    fontFamily: ["Inter"].join(","),
    allVariants: {
      color: BaseThemeConfig.colors.text.primary,
    },
    button: {
      fontSize: pxToRem(16),
      lineHeight: pxToRem(16),
      textTransform: "none",
      fontWeight: 600,
      letterSpacing: "0.0125em",
    },
    h1: {
      fontSize: pxToRem(32),
      lineHeight: pxToRem(48),
      fontWeight: 600,
      letterSpacing: "-0.022em",
    },
    h2: {
      fontSize: pxToRem(24),
      lineHeight: pxToRem(36),
      fontWeight: 600,
      letterSpacing: "0.0025em",
    },
    h3: {
      fontSize: pxToRem(20),
      lineHeight: pxToRem(28),
      fontWeight: 700,
      letterSpacing: "-0.017em",
    },
    h4: {
      fontSize: pxToRem(16),
      lineHeight: pxToRem(24),
      fontWeight: 600,
      letterSpacing: "-0.011em",
    },
    h5: {
      fontSize: pxToRem(14),
      lineHeight: pxToRem(20),
      fontWeight: 600,
      letterSpacing: "0.0125em",
    },
    body1: {
      fontSize: pxToRem(16),
      lineHeight: pxToRem(24),
      fontWeight: 400,
      letterSpacing: "-0.011em",
    },
    body2: {
      fontSize: pxToRem(14),
      lineHeight: pxToRem(20),
      fontWeight: 400,
      letterSpacing: "-0.006em",
    },
    caption: {
      fontSize: pxToRem(12),
      lineHeight: pxToRem(12),
      fontWeight: 400,
    },
    subtitle1: {
      fontSize: pxToRem(12),
      fontWeight: 400,
    },
  },
  shape: {
    borderRadius: 8,
  },
  palette: {
    ...BaseThemeConfig.colors,
    action: {
      disabledBackground: "#CDCBCB !important",
    },
  },
});
```

Can you help me here?

Comment: here are the list of variants in typography, https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/#variants

Comment: may be this article will help you

Answer (score 0):

As of mui@4.x there is no default mechanism to do that. Though you can freely define `MuiTypography` [override](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/?expand-path=$.typography) for arbitrary variant you're going to use other than [standard](https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/#variants). That override will eventually be [filtered out](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.4/packages/material-ui-styles/src/getStylesCreator/getStylesCreator.js#L48) while creating style.

The only sensible way to do what you want in mui@4.x is to use some wrapper component. That will fallback to default `Typography` components for standard variants but use custom stylings for non-standard ones.

```js
import { Typography as MuiTypography, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => // your Typography overrides are available here
const standardVariants = ['h1', ...]

export function Typography(props) {
  if (standardVariants.includes(props.variant)) return <MuiTypography {...props} />

  // your custom typograhy component
}
```